# jxta: does jxse provides a nat tcp traversal solution?

Tags: java, jxta

does jxse provides the mechanism for direct TCP P2P communication behind firewall/NATs i.e through STUNT or ICE? I have scanned through practical JXTA || written by @Vestry and on the related sections but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

JXTA does not use STUN or ICE, it uses its own relay mechanism.
"Endpoint" peers establish outbound connections to a "Relay" peer which binds the connections together. Obviously the IP of the relay must be public or visible to the endpoint peers.
The relay connection is opened using either a JXTA TCP socket or using polling HTTP requests on a selected port of the relay.
A peer can be both a relay and an endpoint.

All this is configured via the NetworkConfigurator.